# Write Text In A Already Existing Text File VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, text, lines, streamwriter

I've been developing a arcade game, and as every good arcade game, it has an incorporated scoreboard so that players can see who scored better. My problem is that everytime it enters a new scoreline, it deletes all the previous lines in the text file. The code I've been using is the following:

```
    If player1 > 25 Then

        objReader.Close()
        MsgBox("O " + jogador1 + " ganhou.")
        tab1.Enabled = False

        Dim wrtScore As String = "C:\Documents and Settings\Joao\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\flaghunter\flaghunter\deposito\scores.txt"
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(wrtScore)

        wrtScore = wrtScore.Trim()

        objWriter.WriteLine(jogador1 + " " + Str(player1))

        objWriter.Close()


    End If
```

Thank you for your attention and any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(wrtScore, TRUE)`
to append to file :D

Comment: Thank you so much. I needed to append to the end of the stack, and this worked perfectly!!! Thank you red Nguyễn, Wayne.

Answer (score 10):

Use [File.AppendText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext.aspx) instead:

```
    // This text is always added, making the file longer over time
    // if it is not deleted.
 Using sw As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(path)
        sw.WriteLine("This")
        sw.WriteLine("is Extra")
        sw.WriteLine("Text")
 End Using
```

This will create the file if it doesn't exist the first time and append the text if the file already exists

Comment: How to append text at the starting position of a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Append to beginning of file, try load contents then overwrite file and drop contents at bottom.
Something Like:

```
Dim sr as New StreamReader("path/to/file.ext")
Dim text as String = sr.ReadToEnd()
sr.Close()
Dim sw as New StreamWriter("path/to/file.ext")
sw.WriteLine("New stuff")
sw.WriteLine("More New Stuff")
sw.WriteLine(text) ' Add original content back
sw.Close()
```