# Saving new scores to text file

Tags: vb.net

Using vb to try and save some scores to a text file in vb and here is some part of the code:

```
addInfo.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "The person-->" & Name & "<-- got a score of " _
  & Score & " out of 10 from class " & form)
addInfo.Close()
```

This is a part of the code and the saving works, except I want the text file to keep the old scores which have been recorded. How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: Duplicate of [Write Text In A Already Existing Text File VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056584/write-text-in-a-already-existing-text-file-vb-net)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't share any code that shows how you are opening your io stream, but here is a general example from [File.AppendText Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Using sw As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(yourfile)
  sw.WriteLine("This is an extra line.")
End Using
```

Comment: @AlexBuzan I don't know what that means.

Comment: sorry I pressed enter for no reason :D